# What Exactly Does SwaggerGen() Method Do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle, .net-8.0

I Recently Start working with **Asp.net Web API** and in the Present of Methods in `Program.cs`.

What does `AddSwaggerGen()` do?

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line of code, adds the `Swagger` generator to the services collection. SwaggerUI shows the REST APIs in your project in a user-friendly UI, so that you can test them in the browser. For this UI to render, you need the `JSON` file that expresses the details of the APIs[name, input arguments, types, etc], that JSON is being generated by this Swagger Generator.

Note: Swagger was the name of the project that described the definition of REST APIs, since 2015 it has been known as `OpenAPI`.

Answer (score 1):

It is Part of the **Swashbuckle** Library, Which Provides Support For Generating

> OpenAPI

and Swagger documentation for your API

Sample of Use it :

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("Your Version", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "Your Version",
        Title = "Your Title Api",
        Description = "Desc",
        TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
        Contact = new OpenApiContact
        {
            Name = "Shayne Boyer",
            Email = string.Empty,
            Url = new Uri("https://socialNet.com/<user>"),
        },
        License = new OpenApiLicense
        {
            Name = "Use under LICX",
            Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license"),
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration action passed to the `AddSwaggerGen` method adds information such as the author, license, and description. You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 0):

`AddSwaggerGen()` method adds a service that generates Swagger documents for your APIs. When this method is called, it adds the service to the dependency injection container so that it can be used later in the application. When the service is used, it will generate a Swagger document that describes the available APIs and their operations. This can be useful for developers who are consuming the APIs, as it provides detailed information about how to use the APIs.